# How to save only the results from the last window in Apache Flink?

Tags: java, java-8, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm processing a text file with the Apache Flink DataStream API where I only have to save as a result the processing results of the last window. How can I do that? How can I filter the results to save only the results coming from the last window?

Comment: if you say about stream you don't know what window is the last one. You can distinguish the most recent one. I feel like your question is not precise- an example could help to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: @wind In dataflow model, batch is a special case of streaming. So, we can have bounded streams in Flink. `env#fromElements` is one such example.